# Accessing Downloads Folder Through gksu

Tags: root, gksu

For some reason when I installed PyCharm, it left all the .exe and the such files in my Downloads folder. I want to move this PyCharm folder to my /opt file, but I need root access. How can I run gksu or any other root access program and gain accessibility to my Downloads folder?

If I run `gksu nautilus`, it does not allow me to view my Downloads folder.

Comment: @ThorOdinson - No, **never** run a GUI application with plain old `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

With `gksu` you switch a user. And please by any means don't use `sudo nautilus`, this can mess up alot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Downloads folder is empty is because `gksu` sets the home directory to root's home directory.

You can access *your* downloads folder at `/home/yourusername/Downloads`

(Obviously, you have to replace "yourusername" with your real user name)

Comment: In one simple line i can be done by **gksu nautilus /home/yourusername/Downloads**